# What volume of elution buffer for plasmid-containing filter paper?

Tags: plasmids

I am attempting to elute a 9kb plasmid from a square of filter paper sent to me to be transformed into DH5a E. coli (photo below). Each filter paper square has been spotted with 1ug of plasmid DNA.

[image: plasmid]

I have two questions:

1. AddGene's protocol states to elute the DNA using 30ul of TE (I'm using H20 as that's all I have atm). Using a similarly sized piece of filter paper to test, I added it + 30ul of h20 to a 1.5ml tube with a quick 4k spin down and have observed that the 30ul is completely absorbed by the paper as shown in the photo. How should I resolve this? Add an additional 30ul? I also tried to use a pipette tip to shove the paper down and squeeze out the water but you can see it didn't work.
2. What volume should I use for transformation knowing that the filter paper contains 1ug and I need to use additional elution volume? Most protocols I've read call for 1-5ul of DNA and AddGene calls for 2ul assuming 30ul elution volume.

Thank you.

[image: elution]

Comment: Are you using the same kind of filter paper (thickness matters)? Did you follow their directions, which say to use 1/2 the piece of filter paper (because they send you a two spots) and to use 30 µL (not the 3 µL you wrote)?

Comment: My sample isn't from AddGene. And I can only estimate it's the same thickness. It seems to be the same based on close inspection. The spot on the paper isn't marked and so I wouldn't know exactly the boundaries to cut out of the paper. The 3ul is an error - I'll fix that now. I used 30ul.

Comment: 1 ug is a LOT of plasmid, so your elution doesn't have to be very efficient. I would figure out how much water your test piece of filter paper can absorb by adding more and spinning down until you start to see free liquid. I would then use double that volume to elute your actual sample, take 30ul and proceed with your transformation.  If your centrifuge is a benchtop eppendorf-style, I'd use the max speed rather than just 4k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is... some.

You only need a tiny amount of plasmid DNA to transform bacteria like DH5$\alpha$, typically in the [1-10 ng range, but much less, as low as about 10 pg (10 picograms) may still work](https://www.addgene.org/protocols/bacterial-transformation/). If you can get even 0.2 ul of the liquid out of that tube, try using that in the transformation.

Things you can try;

1. remove the paper, spin the tube down and see if you can recover even a tiny amount of liquid.
2. Add a bit more liquid - another 30 ul will be fine
3. Snap the tube lid closed on the paper to hold it in place, then spin the liquid out of the paper - this is quite difficult to do.

Note - even with 10% DNA recovery (very low for this method), with 30 ul you will still have 100 ng of DNA, or about 3.3 ng/ul.

Comment: These are all excellent suggestions, especially using the lid to spin out the paper. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, I was able to use a total of 60ul of TBE to elute the plasmid on filter paper, using 1ul for my transformation with success.

Comment: Good, so you probably transformed a few ng. In my experience smaller amounts <5 ng work better than higher amounts anyway.

Comment: Indeed. I did 16 experiments with varying volumes ranging from 1ul to 10ul and the lowest volumes performed best. It was a ~10kb plasmid. I actually posted most of my diy transformation protocol [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/100926/improving-my-diy-friendly-cacl2-competent-cell-prep-heat-shock-protocol).